# Check if input is number and only contains digists 0-9

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using C#.
How would I verify whether an input string is an integer and is only made up of digits 0-9?

An additional requirement is that it should be always made up of exacly 9 digits total; no more, no less.

e.g.,

> OK: 118356737, 111111111, 123423141,
>
> ERROR: 11a334356,
>   1.2.4.535,
>   1112234.222 etc

thanks

Comment: You mean check if it's an integer?

Comment: like this [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/84990ad2-5046-472b-b103-f862bfcd5dbc/) and [This](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CheckNumeric.aspx) ?

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either regex:

```
string input = "123456789";
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{9}$");
```

or LINQ:

```
string input = "123456789";
bool isValid = input.Length == 9 && input.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**. As per the comment, you need to use a regex to ensure all cases are handled correctly.

Check for correct expression with regex

```
string inputStr = "";
if(Regex.IsMatch(inputStr, @"^\d{9}$");) 
{
 //now check for int
 int result;
 if(int.TryParse(inputStr, out result) 
 {
   //it IS an integer 
   //the result integer is in the variable result.
 }
}
```

See msdn for more on [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx). Note: double, float, long etc also have their versions of `TryParse()`.

Comment: That's not going to work because `TryParse` allows white space and sign. So the invalid (according to OP's requirements) string `"    -2345"` would pass your test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to verify the input string.
The pattern below matches 9 numbers, and the first number should not be 0.

`^[1-9]\d{8}$`

Answer (score 0):

add this ajax control

<

```
asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender5" runat="server" TargetControlID="yourtextbox"
                                    FilterType="Custom, Numbers" ValidChars="." />
```

or use regular expression in validation toolbox

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" Style="z-index: 101; left: 424px; position: absolute;
top: 285px" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="check"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work for decimal point, try this

```
string input="12356";
bool valid= Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[-+]?\d+\.?\d*$")); // returns true;



string input="123.456";
bool isValid= Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[-+]?\d+\.?\d*$")); //returns true


string input="12%3.456";
bool isValid= Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[-+]?\d+\.?\d*$")); //returns false
```

[Click here For Detailed Description](http://codeissue.com/issues/i24e27059aec154/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-integer-or-not-in-c)